# Witcher 2 how to drop a bomb

Tags: the-witcher-2

Regarding trying to destroy the Nikker's nest in Witcher 2: I'm trying to fire either drop the bomb I've already made bombs I can't figure out how to release it of trying on keyboard and with the gamepad.

Answer (score 1):

To destroy the nest, you need a specific type of bomb. Your nekker knowledge or a a book should tell you this. (Grapeshot)

When you have this bomb, you can use it as a simple left click dialog near the the nest.

To use bombs in general, put them into your quick access bar in the top right of your inventory, select them and throw them using the corresponding button.